# randomly replace a substring in a block of text in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how would i randomly replace a string in a text using javascript or jquery?

given: `<p>foo bar foo baz foo</p>`

I want to just randomly replace 1 occurrence of 'foo' with 'buz', so possible results would be:

```
<p>buz bar foo baz foo</p>
<p>foo bar buz baz foo</p>
<p>foo bar foo baz buz</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $element = $('p');
var string = 'foo';
var count = $element.text().match(string, 'g').length;

if(count) {
    var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * count) + 1);
    $element.text(function(i, text) {
        var matchNumber = 0;
        return text.replace(new RegExp(string, 'g'), function(text) {
            matchNumber++;
            if(matchNumber == rand) {
                return 'buz';
            }
            return text;
        });
    });
}
```

**Explanation**:
First of all we have to know the range to the `random`. We can get it matching the string and then get the `length`.

Then you have to match it again and increase a counter which will be used to know which match is the currently one.

If the current match is equal to the random number we have to replace the text.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/yK6JM/)

Comment: This works perfectly...except I have one rub -- I want to do the replacement 1 or 2 times at random. So BUZ would show up once or twice in the result.